# How to create a reference to an anonymouse addEventListener handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

```javascript
function alertString(str) {
    alert(str);
}

var str = "hello";
var alert_string = document.getElementById("alert_str");

// this can be removed with removeEventListener
// alert_str.addEventListener("click", alertString, false);

// but since I need to pass an argument
// alertString is wrapped within an anonymouse function
alert_string.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alertString(str);
}, false);

document.getElementById("remove_alert").onclick = function() {
    alert_string.removeEventListener("click", alertString, false);
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="alert_str" value="alert" />
<input type="button" id="remove_alert" value="remove alert" />
```

The click event handler cannot be removed since it is wrapped inside an anonymouse function.

How can I create a reference to that function so I can remove alertString from the alert button?

Answer (score 2):

Quickest, simplest method:

```
function alertStringWrapper() {
    alertString(str);
}
alert_string.addEventListener("click", alertStringWrapper, false);
```